# How to return a path with '*' in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I can use a particular index to get data from a known location:

```
SELECT ('{"a": [{"age":10},{"age":20}]}'::jsonb)->'a' -> 0 -> 'age';
# 10
```

However, how would I get all values at that location? I want to get `[10, 20]` with something like:

```
SELECT ('{"a": [{"age":10},{"age":20}]}'::jsonb)->'a' -> '*' -> 'age';
```

But I guess the `*` operator isn't supported here? How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The native operators won't work here but [JSONPath is supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) in Postgres and you can use one of those functions that supports it, for example:

```
WITH tbl(v) AS (
    SELECT '{"a": [{"age":10},{"age":20}]}'::jsonb
)
SELECT jsonb_path_query(v, '$.a[*].age') FROM tbl;
------------------
 10
 20
(2 rows)
```